# Rails: Load a div in bootstrap modal, after the modal has been displayed fully

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fairly simple question. I have a bootstrap modal with a div that I want to load only once the modal has fired. I am using..

```
 $('#ResultsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#ResultsChart').show()
  })
```

The div is nothing particularly special:

```
<div id = "ResultsChart">
    Some interesting results here
</div>
```

The point is I don't want a "show", "hide" solution. I want the div to actually load after the modal. I had thought about using a partial and loading that in using a .js.erb file but I couldn't see how that could be done from the button the fires the modal. I suspect I am making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I want the modal to display and once displayed, load in the div

Comment: so you want to display chart in bootstrap modal right?

Comment: when model show event fire you can append data in it..

Comment: Ok...so could you give me an example

Comment: `shown.bs.modal` inside this event you can use `$('.model-body').html("<%render partial%>")`